# Counting the degree of unsaturation

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

What is the difference between a ring and an aromatic ring here (degree of unsaturation)?

For a benzene molecule, they count it as four, so it seems like benzene contains a ring...
 but doesn't it contain an aromatic ring? I am very confused.

[image]

Comment: Ignore that line altogether, as if there were no such thing as aromatic ring. Benzene contains a ring (1) and three double bonds (3*1), thus making a total of 4, that's it, period.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would suggest you to ignore these lines in your textbook and simply use some formulas for finding the degree of unsaturation of compounds.
For a hydrocarbon,
DU = ((2×C+2) - H)/2
For a compound having carbon, hydrogen and nitrogen,
DU = ((2×C+2) - (H - N))/2
For a compound having carbon, hydrogen and oxygen,
DU = ((2×C+2) - H)/2
For a compound having carbon, hydrogen and any halogen,
DU = ((2×C+2) - (H + X))/2
where, DU is degree of unsaturation
             C is no. of carbon atoms
             H is no. of hydrogen atoms
             N is no. of nitrogen atoms
             X is no. of halogen atoms